# App permissions page in android app on play store

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I published my app on play store. But when I press install for installing any other app on play store. One app permissions page open. And it contains permissions like Phone calls, Network communication, Your location, Network communications and so on. But when I click install on my app in play store. App permissions page open that contains text **Laughing Buddha does not require any special permissions**. How can I add permissions like in other apps when someone click on install on my app in play store?

Comment: Add the permissions in your application's manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application need any special permission you can add in Manifest. Its your choice. If the app does't need any permission it will show like **Laughing Buddha does not require any special permissions**

Comment: ok it means the permissions added in manifest file are visible there?